# Ironpython 3.4 not letting me install from pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, ironpython

So I recently upgraded to IronPython3.4. I have set the environment variables up however when I try to install something using pip I get a lot of errors. I tried this:

```
ipy -X:Frames -m pip install xlrd
```

And it returned this:

```
Collecting xlrd
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 376, in prepare_files
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._prepare_file(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 551, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 728, in __init__
    self.parsed = html5lib.parse(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 35, in parse
    return p.parse(doc, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 235, in parse
    self._parse(stream, False, None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 85, in _parse
    self.tokenizer = _tokenizer.HTMLTokenizer(stream, parser=self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_tokenizer.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.stream = HTMLInputStream(stream, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 151, in HTMLInputStream
    return HTMLBinaryInputStream(source, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 428, in __init__
    self.charEncoding = self.determineEncoding(useChardet)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 475, in determineEncoding
    charEncoding = self.detectEncodingMeta(), "tentative"
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 576, in detectEncodingMeta
    encoding = parser.getEncoding()
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 707, in getEncoding
    if self.data.matchBytes(key):
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 668, in matchBytes
    data = self[p:p + len(bytes)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `ipy -X:Frames -m` to install the package?

Comment: @brance On the IronPython official website it shows this is how you use pip with IronPython: 
 https://ironpython.net/blog/2014/12/07/pip-in-ironpython-275.html